# yaml.parser.ParserError - why does it not work?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

What's wrong?

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block collection
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 23, column 9
expected <block end>, but found '?'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 24, column 9
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  idserver:
    image: israelinfo-idserver
#    ports:
#      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - idserver-data:/home/vhosts/israelinfo/data
    networks:
      - back
  nginx:
    image: israelinfo-nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - back
networks:
  back:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
        gateway: 172.16.238.1
volumes:
  idserver-data:
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. `gateway` is part of the same dictionary as `subnet` and needs to be indented by two spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors:

1. gateway for IPAM is a feature of compose-file version 2
2. As larsks suggested, you need to indent gateway by two more spaces

> Note: Additional IPAM configurations, such as gateway, are only
>   honored for version 2 at the moment.

(documentation link https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam)